# Compare data between Pandas series and Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have one Information csv , I used below to filter some specific name(Rony) from a column(Names) like below.  Need help where marked in bold.

```
df= pd.read_csv('Info.csv',index_col=False)
App_=df[df['Names']=='Rony']
df_address=[]
address=App['Address']
df_address.append(address)
```

# **This is printing result with index, I do not want to see index .Can index be avoided to print or remove in df_address ?**

```
print(df_address)
dct=next(os.walk('.'))[1]
```

#**Below is not working** **, Need help to fix this.How it can work with pandas.Need to check if directories name are available in df_address**

```
for i in df_address:        
    if i in dct:
        #Do Some operation
```

Comment: You said, "Below is not working". Do you get any errors?

Comment: `Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1121, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to append to a new list explicitly. There is functionality within `pandas` to convert a series to a list directly:

```
df_address = App['Address'].tolist()
```

Moreover, you can chain operations to make your logic more readable. For example, you can filter by row and column simultaneously:

```
df_address = df.loc[df['Names'] == 'Rony', 'Address']\
               .tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me about `tolist()` it fixed the entire issue :)

Comment: os.walk - how it can be done recursively for directory? I have to write this but it seems long  - `for i in directories:
    print(i)
    l=next(os.walk(i))[1]
    for k in l:
        print(k)`

Comment: I'm not sure. You may need to ask a separate question.